# Java eror on INNER Join query

Tags: java, mysql, maven, join, inner-join

I have Inteliej IDEA and eror on MYSQL Script.
I Have a 2 tables contacts and organization.
Need to get All contacts where Name start with letter like A or any letter input to console
Where name of organization "Cats" or any inputted to console.

```
Table contacts
contact_id  organization_id first_name last_name
2                 2               Anna       Horodova
3                 4               Serhey     Pankiv
4                 3               Oleh       Ivanov
etc...

Table organizations
organization_id  contact_id organization_name
2                    null            Cats
3                    null            Dogs
4                    null            Cows
etc...
```

relations Many to many
My MSQL query on Java code

```
        return sql="SELECT * from contacts where first_name LIKE'"
                +letter+"%'"+"INNER JOIN organizations ON contacts.contact_id = organizations.contact_id";
    }
```

and i have the error

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN organizations ON contacts.contact_id = organizations.contact_id' at line 1
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1200)
>       at ua.oleh.service.Main.main(Main.java:44)

If i use a only `Select *` with searching by letter it works but
    I use Inteliej IDEA 2019
MYSQL with Workbench 8.0
and use Maven
pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Salesforce</groupId>
    <artifactId>Salesforce</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

In the example I see

```
SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.name = tableB.name
```

Comment: The `where` clause goes *after* the `from` clause (which includes the `join`s): `select ... from ... inner join ... where ...`

Comment: I need use where in end of join, yes?

Comment: It's help. Thank you.